# Put an android screen to sleep in React Native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, mobile

I've got a react-native application that accepts web requests and displays information. It runs on android exclusively.

I need to turn off the screen automatically after some time, and then turn it on when a new request comes through. This will all have to be done programmatically without manual input from the user. It's being run on a raspberry pi if that is of any help.

I've seen some others ask questions about this topic, but I can't nail down the 'best' way to do this. setTimeouts are even tricky in this application because of the way that react deals with state.

What would be a good solution? Is this something that is feasible in react-native or would it be better to try to add some code "under the hood" in kotlin or java?

It's such a simple scenario but I can't find a straightforward way of achieving this! Thank you!